# Tomcat is unable to start

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to using Amazon SNS servlet in my project. However, Tomcat gives me errors like this:

```
 Nov 26, 2015 1:28:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I have read a lot of solutions to similar problems, like:

1. We cannot have duplicate jars in Web-INF/lib, especially servlet.jar because it may be in conflict with Tomcat's configuration.
2. check your .classpath or web.xml file.

etc.

But after I have tried everything, it still didn't work.

This is my classpath:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.AWS_JAVA_SDK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.json-20120521.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-async-4.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-examples-4.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/Liang/Documents/workspace/tweetMap/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>tweetMap</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>GoogleMap.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SNSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SNSServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SNSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SNSServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

This is my SNSServlet.java:

```
public class SNSServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SNSServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SecurityException{
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xx","xxx");
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper().withCredentials(credentials);


        //Get the message type header.
        String messagetype = request.getHeader("x-amz-sns-message-type");
        //If message doesn't have the message type header, don't process it.
        if (messagetype == null)
            return;

        // Parse the JSON message in the message body
        // and hydrate a Message object with its contents 
        // so that we have easy access to the name/value pairs 
        // from the JSON message.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            builder.append(scan.nextLine());
        }

        SNSMessage msg = readMessageFromJson(builder.toString());

        // The signature is based on SignatureVersion 1. 
        // If the sig version is something other than 1, 
        // throw an exception.
        if (msg.getSignatureVersion().equals("1")) {
            // Check the signature and throw an exception if the signature verification fails.
            if (isMessageSignatureValid(msg))
                System.out.println(">>Signature verification succeeded");
            else {
                System.out.println(">>Signature verification failed");
                throw new SecurityException("Signature verification failed.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(">>Unexpected signature version. Unable to verify signature.");
            throw new SecurityException("Unexpected signature version. Unable to verify signature.");
        }

        // Process the message based on type.
        if (messagetype.equals("Notification")) {
            //TODO: Do something with the Message and Subject.
            //Just log the subject (if it exists) and the message.
            String logMsgAndSubject = ">>Notification received from topic " + msg.getTopicArn();
            if (msg.getSubject() != null)
                logMsgAndSubject += " Subject: " + msg.getSubject();
            logMsgAndSubject += " Message: " + msg.getMessage();
            String mes = msg.getMessage();
            System.out.println(logMsgAndSubject);

        }


        else if (messagetype.equals("SubscriptionConfirmation"))
        {
            //TODO: You should make sure that this subscription is from the topic you expect. Compare topicARN to your list of topics 
            //that you want to enable to add this endpoint as a subscription.

            //Confirm the subscription by going to the subscribeURL location 
            //and capture the return value (XML message body as a string)
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL(msg.getSubscribeURL()).openStream());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(sc.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(">>Subscription confirmation (" + msg.getSubscribeURL() +") Return value: " + sb.toString());
            //TODO: Process the return value to ensure the endpoint is subscribed.
            SNSHelper.INSTANCE.confirmTopicSubmission(msg);
        }
        else if (messagetype.equals("UnsubscribeConfirmation")) {
            //TODO: Handle UnsubscribeConfirmation message. 
            //For example, take action if unsubscribing should not have occurred.
            //You can read the SubscribeURL from this message and 
            //re-subscribe the endpoint.
            System.out.println(">>Unsubscribe confirmation: " + msg.getMessage());
        }
        else {
            //TODO: Handle unknown message type.
            System.out.println(">>Unknown message type.");
        }
        System.out.println(">>Done processing message: " + msg.getMessageId());
    }


    private boolean isMessageSignatureValid(SNSMessage msg) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(msg.getSigningCertUrl());
            InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
            inStream.close();

            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
            sig.update(getMessageBytesToSign(msg));
            return sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(msg.getSignature().getBytes()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Verify method failed.", e);

        }
    }

    private byte[] getMessageBytesToSign(SNSMessage msg) {

        byte [] bytesToSign = null;
        if (msg.getType().equals("Notification"))
            bytesToSign = buildNotificationStringToSign(msg).getBytes();
        else if (msg.getType().equals("SubscriptionConfirmation") || msg.getType().equals("UnsubscribeConfirmation"))
            bytesToSign = buildSubscriptionStringToSign(msg).getBytes();
        return bytesToSign;
    }

    //Build the string to sign for Notification messages.
    private static String buildNotificationStringToSign( SNSMessage msg) {
        String stringToSign = null;

        //Build the string to sign from the values in the message.
        //Name and values separated by newline characters
        //The name value pairs are sorted by name 
        //in byte sort order.
        stringToSign = "Message\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getMessage() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "MessageId\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getMessageId() + "\n";
        if (msg.getSubject() != null) {
            stringToSign += "Subject\n";
            stringToSign += msg.getSubject() + "\n";
        }
        stringToSign += "Timestamp\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getTimestamp() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "TopicArn\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getTopicArn() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "Type\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getType() + "\n";
        return stringToSign;
    }
    //
    //  //Build the string to sign for SubscriptionConfirmation 
    //  //and UnsubscribeConfirmation messages.
    private static String buildSubscriptionStringToSign(SNSMessage msg) {
        String stringToSign = null;
        //Build the string to sign from the values in the message.
        //Name and values separated by newline characters
        //The name value pairs are sorted by name 
        //in byte sort order.
        stringToSign = "Message\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getMessage() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "MessageId\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getMessageId() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "SubscribeURL\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getSubscribeURL() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "Timestamp\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getTimestamp() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "Token\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getToken() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "TopicArn\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getTopicArn() + "\n";
        stringToSign += "Type\n";
        stringToSign += msg.getType() + "\n";
        return stringToSign;
    }
    //
    //
    private SNSMessage readMessageFromJson(String string) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        SNSMessage message = null;
        try {
            message = mapper.readValue(string, SNSMessage.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

Really appreciated for any suggestions..

Thanks you all!

Comment: You name you servlet as servelet.java and declaring class name as SNSServlet . make sure you are saving as SNSServlet .java

Comment: Thanks for your attention. However, my .java file was indeed named as SNSServlet.java

Comment: Please write here the path of your java file and web.xml

Comment: Recently I had problems to start tomcat on my local machines after the java update8. This update deleted the jre7 folders that Tomcat was using. Are you sure that is not the problem?